# Tekken: What is the fighting style "Mimicry"?

Tags: tekken-5

After doing some research on Tekken (5:DR) characters, I found that Mokujin, the wooden trainer "dummy", has a fighting style called "mimicry". However, I am unable to find out more about mimicry.

The name would suggest that he adapts his fighting style depending on whom he is fighting. I cannot find evidence on this however.

**What is the fighting style "mimicry" in the Tekken series?**

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mokujin), Mokujin "mimics fighting styles from other characters, which vary from match to match."

This [GameFaqs link](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/208-fighting-games/6710830) mentions that "Mokujin randomly copies the fighting styles of all the other Tekken 3 fighters except Ogre & Anna Williams."

Comment: You say randomly - does that mean you could be versing someone who does some form of wrestling (eg. King) and Mokujin could be doing something like Ninjutsu (eg. Yoshimitsu)?

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information from Jazzachi's answer:

As learnt from recent experience after playing Tekken 5: DR on PSP, Mokujin does have random fighting styles, which does not deppend on the opponent. Due to the vast number of fighting styles, I highly recommend that only experienced players play Mokujin as they have had experience with many/all fighting styles. Mokujin changes the fighting style each round (? I guess that is the correct sports term).


Tip: Before fighting, you can tell by Mokujin's pre-battle taunt and his stance what character he is mimicing, thus what fighting style he is using. This is assuming you have great experience with the game, though. Because he changes, if you lose to a character, it could get easier if he changes to a fighting style you are use to, OR it could get worse (it changes to *cough cough* Steve).
It gets quite interesting when he mimics characters such as Roger Jr. and Yoshimitsu.

As for the lore of Tekken, I can make a pretty safe bet by saying he uses various techniques off fighting as he has learnt of those who practiced on him.